# CakePHP MAMP mod_rewrite not working?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, mamp

Been delving into PHP and the Cake framework recently and trying to set up a new project using Cake 2.4.7 with MAMP on my MacBook.

I want to use the DebugKit plugin, during installation it suggests my mod-rewrite is not configured correctly as none of the DebugKit's styling seems to be loading.  I feel like I've tried everything that people are suggesting to get it working but nothing seems to do the trick.

Here is a list of all the things I have found on forums so far and tried, if anyone has anything else I can try I will be very grateful!

1. `git clone https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit.git` in `app/Plugin` directory which created `debug_kit`
2. added/uncommented `CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');` in `app/Config/bootstrap.php`
3. added `Configure::write('debug', 2);` in `app/Config/core.php`
4. removed `?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>` from `app/View/Layouts/default.ctp`
5. added `.htaccess` in project root directory:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```
6. checked `.htaccess` in my `app` directory:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```
7. checked `.htaccess` in my `app/webroot` directory:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```
8. checked output of `echo phpinfo();` for `mod_rewrite` which was present
9. in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` replaced all `AllowOverride None` changed to `AllowOverride All` for `<Directory>` directives
10. commented out `echo $this->Html->css(array('cake.generic.css'));` in case it was getting in the way

And still the debug kit toolbar looks like this:

[image: debug kit toolbar not working]

Comment: How about not editing the .htaccess files? Leave them how they are with cakephp default.

Comment: Just reverted them all back to the defaults, looks like I added a couple of things in my attempts to fix the issue.  But still not same result I'm afraid, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!  Somewhere along the line I thought it was a good idea to uncomment this line in `Config/core.php`:

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
```

But this is for when url rewriting is NOT enabled, so putting the comment back in did the trick!